# Por que algumas ações dão erro se eu não especificar o View como parâmetro no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um app de teste com os conhecimentos básicos que adquiri sobre android já que anteriormente eu era programador java. Todos os tutoriais que pesquisei as pessoas colocavam a classe `View` como parâmetro padrão em seus métodos, mas ninguém explicava o por que, e hj eu fui testar nesta aplicação se funcionava sem passar como parâmetro a classe `View` e incrivelmente deu erro! Gostaria de saber por que é necessário passar a classe View como parâmetro dos meus métodos e se em algum caso eu posso omitir (especifique)?

```
public void abrirBrowser(View view) {
    Uri url = Uri.parse("http://google.com.br");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Consegue exemplificar esse comportamento?? Nao sao todos os metodos que precisam de view.. Depende do que voce vai fazer, mas de um exemplo de codigo pra clarificar

Comment: Vou dar um exemplo:

Comment: Exemplo foi dado na atualização da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view como parâmetro só é obrigatória em métodos que você define no atributo "android:onclick" das views no XML, pois internamente o Android seta um onClickListener para as mesmas através do método definido (no seu caso, o "abrirBrowser") quando elas são infladas no app, e esse listener é uma interface que implementa o método onClick() que requer uma view como parâmetro.

Por exemplo, em vez de definir o método no XML (e deixar o Android criar o listener automaticamente), você poderia manualmente setar o listener no código dessa forma, que chamaria o seu método sem a necessidade de passar a view como parâmetro (pois você já passou no método da interface):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        abrirBrowser();
    }
});
```

Para os métodos que você cria normalmente, não há necessidade de parâmetros obrigatórios.